# FHIR Server For Azure: Is there a way to return a specific resource without paging?

Tags: fhir-server-for-azure

I have a FHIR Server For Azure implemented in a development environment.  I need to provide a list with the latest 10 lab results for a given patient to a client application.  I’ve been trying to get the data with a request like:

GET [base]/DiagnosticReport?_sort=-date&_count=100

But the sorting is not working.  Based on the FHIR Server for Azure features, is not yet supported.  If I leave the client application to sort the result, then I need to send all the labs for the given patient.  But the max quantity of resources returned is 100 and then it start paging.  Is there a way I can get all the results without paging?